# Bootstrap table different colors

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know how to change styles of the table rows in bootstrap according.

It seems for that they run js against each row. However not sure about that.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: To clarify, you mean a Bootstrap accordion using the Collapse plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you would want to use .table-striped class. It uses CSS nth-child selector for alternate styling